# How do I reference a function that is within the class as a command for a menu button?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, menu, command

This is the code:

```
class applicationUI(Frame):

    def vGuitarRender():
        print("Rendering")

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        menu = Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu) 
        menu.add_command(label = "Virtual Guitar", command = vGuitarRender)
```

Error is this:

```
menu.add_command(label = "Virtual Guitar", command = vGuitarRender)
NameError: name 'vGuitarRender' is not defined
```

It would be great to have some advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

`vGuitarRender` is a method within your class, so you need to use `self.vGuitarRender` instead.

```
menu.add_command(label = "Virtual Guitar", command = self.vGuitarRender)
```